# what is LDC metrics and fullform of LDC

Tags: dgml

I tried googling.MY friend has to give a seminar on DGML(Design Markup language) and he is unable to figure what is LDC which he has come across on studying the DGML paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deduced, from the same paper your friend reads probably, that LDC stands for Local Declarations Count.